# Not reading last option value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

So I have this test code to a major project. This code is connecting to the database perfectly and doing almost everything I was set to. But when I select the last value from the dropdown list it just wont give me it's value for no aparent reason. 
Here is an example of what I want.

[image]

Here is an example of the "bug".

[image]

Here is the complete code (except for the connection).

```
<?php
include_once('ligacao.php');
//Check connection
if (!$link) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $pesq = $_GET['id'];
    $atual = $_GET['atual'];

    //Distrito e concelho
    $sql = ("SELECT distrito,concelho FROM concelhos WHERE codg_cc = '$pesq'");
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $dist = $row['distrito'];
        $conc = $row['concelho'];
    }

    //echo ($atual);
    if (isset($atual) and strlen($atual) > 0) {
        $sql3 = ("SELECT DISTINCT new_name_freg,cod_freg_new FROM freguesias WHERE cod_freg_new = '$atual'");
        $result3 = mysql_query($sql3, $link);

        $sql2 = ("SELECT old_name_freg,cod_freg_old FROM freguesias WHERE cod_freg_new = '$atual'");
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $link);
    } else {
        $sql3 = ("SELECT DISTINCT new_name_freg,cod_freg_new FROM freguesias WHERE codg_cc = '$pesq' ORDER BY new_name_freg");
        $result3 = mysql_query($sql3, $link);
    }

    mysql_free_result($result);
}

/* $atual=$_GET['atual']; // This line is added to take care if your global variable is off
  if(isset($atual) and strlen($atual) > 0){
  //echo ('hello');
  $sql2=("SELECT old_name_freg,cod_freg_old FROM freguesias WHERE cod_freg_new = '$atual'");
  $result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $link);
  } */

/*
  } // else{$quer="SELECT DISTINCT subcategory,subcat_id FROM subcategory order by subcategory"; }
  ////////// end of query for second subcategory drop down list box ///////////////////////////
 */

mysqli_close($ligar);
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            /*function reload(form)
             {
             val=$pesq;
             self.location='Formulario2.php?id=' + val ;
             } */

            function reload3(form)
            {
                var concelho = '<?= $pesq ?>'; //passa a variavel de php para o javascript
//alert(concelho);
//alert(element.defaultValue);
//alert(self.location);
                val2 = (form.value);
                self.location = 'Formulario2.php?id=' + concelho + '&atual=' + val2;

            }

        </script>
    </head> 
    <body onload=enable_text(false);>
        <div >
            <table>
                <form name=f1 action="" >       
                    <td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID:</td> <td><input type="number" name="id" value="<?php echo $pesq; ?>"></td>
                        <td><input type="submit" value="Obter informações"></td>
                    </tr>
                    </td>
                </form> 
            </table>        
            <form name=f2 action="" >
                <table> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>Distrito:</td><td ><input type="text" name="distrito" maxlength="25" value="<?php echo $dist; ?>"></td>        
                        <td>Concelho:</td> <td><input type="text" name="concelho" maxlength="25" value="<?php echo $conc; ?>"></td><br>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Freguesias:</td>
                        <td>Designação atual :</td> <td><select name="atual" onchange="reload3(this)"><option value=''>Selecione uma freguesia</option>                     
                                <?php
                                while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3)) {
                                    echo "<option size=30 selected value=" . $row3["cod_freg_new"] . ">" . $row3["new_name_freg"] . "</option>";
                                }
                                mysql_free_result($result3);
                                ?>
                            </select></td>                      

                        <td>Designação antiga :</td> <td><select name="antiga" onchange="reload3(this"><option value=''>Select One</option>
<?php
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    echo "<option size=30 value=" . $row2["cod_freg_old"] . ">" . $row2["old_name_freg"] . "</option>";
}
mysql_free_result($result2);
?>
                            </select></td>
                        </form>



                    </tr>
                    <tr>    
                        <td>Número da mesa:</td> <td><input type="number" name="mesa" min="1" max="15"></td><br>
                    <td>Localização da mesa:</td> <td><input type="text" name="local" maxlength="40"></td><br>
                    </tr>
                    <td>Todos os eleitores desta frequesia: <input type="checkbox" name=todos onclick="enable_text(this.checked)" ></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nº de eleitor inicial do caderno </td><td><input type=text name=intini1 maxlength=5></td><td><input type=number name=intini2 maxlength=5></td>
                        <td>Nº de eleitor final do caderno </td><td><input type=text name=intfim1 maxlength=5></td><td><input type=number name=intfim2 maxlength=5></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr><br>    
                    <td>Nota:</td> <td><input type="text" name="nota" maxlength="40"></td><br>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you have any question about the code or you need me to clarify my question better do not be shy to tell me so.

P.S: I know I should use `mysqli` instead of `myslq_` and also prepared statements but I'm trying to focus on the real issues instead of security. Pardon me if my english is bad.

Here is the html source as requested.

```
<form name="f2" action="">
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Distrito:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="distrito" maxlength="25" value="Faro"></td>
            <td>Concelho:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="concelho" maxlength="25" value="Albufeira"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Freguesias:</td>
            <td>Designação atual :</td>
            <td><select name="atual" onchange="reload3(this)">
                  <option value="">Selecione uma freguesia</option>
                  <option size="30" selected="" value="080106">Albufeira e Olhos de Ãgua</option>
                  <option size="30" selected="" value="080104">Ferreiras</option>
                  <option size="30" selected="" value="080102">Guia</option>
                  <option size="30" selected="" value="080103">Paderne</option>
               </select></td>
            <td>Designação antiga :</td>
            <td><select name="antiga" onchange="reload3(this">
                  <option value="">Select One</option>
               </select></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Número da mesa:</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="mesa" min="1" max="15"></td>
            <td>Localização da mesa:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="local" maxlength="40"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Todos os eleitores desta frequesia:
               <input type="checkbox" name="todos" onclick="enable_text(this.checked)"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Nº de eleitor inicial do caderno </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="intini1" maxlength="5"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="intini2" maxlength="5"></td>
            <td>Nº de eleitor final do caderno </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="intfim1" maxlength="5"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="intfim2" maxlength="5"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Nota:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nota" maxlength="40"></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript code as requested.

```
function reload3(form)
{
var concelho = '<?= $pesq ?>'; //passa a variavel de php para o javascript
//alert(concelho);
//alert(element.defaultValue);
//alert(self.location);
val2=(form.value);
self.location='Formulario2.php?id=' + concelho + '&atual=' + val2;

}
```

**Update:** The person that I'm working found a better solution using JQuery which solved the problem. Thank you all the guys who helped.

Comment: Please show the generated html, probably the value is badly formed, eg has a quote in it or something

Comment: Try adding quotes around value in option.

Comment: The picture helps explain the problem, but could you please add the html source as requested - eg right click > view source in your browser and paste the form html

Comment: @jcubic Thank you for the help. I have added the quotes and it wasn't the solution.

Comment: @Steve Thank you for the help. I have added the source code in the answer. Sorry for not understanding what you said.

Comment: You have error in your code `onchange="reload3(this"` missing parenthesis.

Comment: @jcubic Thank you for your answer. Weirdly enough that "error" is making part of my code making it's function. I just noticed and I can't explain why. When I corrected it my function stoped working so I think I will have to live with that error.

Comment: If you have that error reload3 will not be executed.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in your javascript. Can you show your javascript code?

Comment: @jcubic Thank you for your answer. That's the thing. It executes.

Comment: @jcubic I have inserted the javascript in the question.

Comment: Open your browser's console and check if the ajax request is returning what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 errors in your code, the first one is you are missing a closing parenthesis, which means you'll get a javascript error when it executes:

```
onchange="reload3(this"
```

change it to

```
onchange="reload3(this)"
```

Next, you got 2 forms named f1 and f2, the submit button is in form f1 which contains 1 input named id. So when you press the submit button, you'll get only id with it.

There is no submit button in f2, so you'll never submit the form, only the onchange() call make a location change with both id and atual once you have fixed the error I mentioned above. But if you had a submit button, you'll be missing id, because id is in form f1.

Remember that a submit button, submit the form with its input/select elements. Not elements from other forms.

Finally, all your form actions are empty and default to get, but this is a bad practice to leave them empty.